# Elixir santize strings with \"

Tags: elixir

After obtaining headers from an API response, I have the following string:

```
"\"Web Service Authentication\""
```

Whats the simplest way to sanitize these strings into:

```
"Web Service Authentication"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `String.replace/3` to remove quotes

```
"\"Web Service Authentication\"" |> String.replace("\"", "")
```

or `String.trim/2` if quotes are only on sides

```
"\"Web Service Authentication\"" |> String.trim("\"")
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get this too, wondering if theres anything nicer.

Comment: What do you mean by "nicer"?

Comment: Sigils make it easier to read: `String.trim(~S["Web Service Authentication"], ~S["])`

Answer (score 2):

I think `String.trim/2` will be your best friend here (I'm assuming quotes are just your first and last characters), but if you're looking for a pattern matching approach:

```rb
iex> length = byte_size("\"Web Service Authentication\"") - 2
26
iex> <<?", trimmed::bytes-size(length), ?">> = "\"Web Service Authentication\""
"\"Web Service Authentication\""
iex> trimmed
"Web Service Authentication"
```

Comment: `~S("Web Service Authentication") |> (&(binary_part(&1, 1, byte_size(&1) - 2))).()`

Answer (score 1):

Esoteric example with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) comprehension

```rb
# removes all occurences of quotes
for <<c <- "\"hello world\"">>, c != ?", into: "", do: <<c>>  
#⇒ "hello world"
```

---

Recursively:

```rb
defmodule Trim do
  # removes all occurences of quotes
  def drop(s, what \\ <<?">>), do: do_drop(s, what, "")

  defp do_drop("", _what, acc), do: acc
  defp do_drop(<<?">> <> rest, what, acc),
    do: do_drop(rest, what, acc)
  defp do_drop(<<c :: binary-size(1), rest :: binary>>, what, acc),
    do: do_drop(rest, what, acc <> c)
end

Trim.drop(~s|\"foo\"|)
```

---

Pure esoteric through lists:

```rb
# removes opening and closing quotes only
with ["\""|s] <- :erlang.binary_to_list(~s|"foo"|),
     s <- :lists.reverse(s),
     ["\""|s] <- s,
     s <- :lists.reverse(s),
  do: :erlang.list_to_binary(s)
#⇒ "foo"
```